# Get Avg to work together with count in group by SQL clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a SQL clause that looks like the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 ir.ItemID, it.Title, count(ir.ItemID) as amount
  FROM [eboghandel].[dbo].[ItemReviews] ir
  LEFT JOIN Items it on ir.ItemID = it.ID
  group by ItemID, it.Title
  order by amount desc
```

This works perfectly, and I get a list of items with most reviews.

However, I also want to show the "average" rating of this score.

I can easily do:

```
  SELECT Avg(Rating) FROM ItemReviews WHERE ItemID = '5324181'
```

Which will give my average, but I want to combine this with the previous query.

I tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 ir.ItemID, it.Title, count(ir.ItemID) as amount, avg(ir.Rating)
  FROM [eboghandel].[dbo].[ItemReviews] ir
  LEFT JOIN Items it on ir.ItemID = it.ID
  group by ItemID, it.Title, ir.Rating
  order by amount desc
```

But this one have two issues.

- It calculates wrong (ahem)
- It seems to remove some reviews so the count is different

Any idea how I can fix this SQL call?

Comment: I think you cannot combine the two in one select statement because in your first select statement you have like 1000 rows (top 1000) while the 2nd statement which is the average, you only have 1 row. Combining the two will definitely give you a wrong result.

Comment: or unless it's fine to you to have the average repeating 1000 times.

Comment: When group by, columns shall either be specified in GROUP BY,  or argument to an aggregate function (count, avg etc)! (If both, you will get the average for a specific value, which is that specific value...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using common table expression can help you solve the problem. Written below is an untested code, you can perhaps write something along the same lines.

```
;with cte
as
(
SELECT TOP 1000 ir.ItemID item_id, it.Title title, count(ir.ItemID) as amount
  FROM [eboghandel].[dbo].[ItemReviews] ir
  LEFT JOIN Items it on ir.ItemID = it.ID
  group by ItemID, it.Title
)
select item_id, title, amount, avg(rating) from cte join ItemReviews ir
on cte.item_id=ir.id
group by item_id, title, amount
order by amount
```